# C++ Operator Overloading with Primitive Types

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, user-defined-types

How do I define an operator where one operand is a defined type and the other is an int?
I have a class`Damage` and defined as such in `Damage.h`:

```
#pragma once

class Damage
{
public:
    Damage(int, int = 0, int = 0);

    int operator-= (int& num)
    {
        return num - this->GetDamage();
    }

private:
    int damage;
    int dotDamage;
    int dotDamageLength;
};
```

And I am trying to use the operator like this in `Monster.cpp`:

```
#include "Monster.h"
#include "Damage.h"

int Monster::TakeDamage(Damage&  damage)
{
    this->health -= damage;        // Error Here
    return this->health;
}
```

The error is:
    "No operator "-=" matches these operands.
    operand types are int -= damage.

I have also tried using the `-` operator too, among my many attempts, defining it outside the class, passing in two different parameters, but nothing has worked yet.

Comment: The way you wrote Monster::TakeDamage, "health" should be a class as well (not an int), accepting the Damage class for the overloded operator... (and access the int values inside the operator).

Comment: I considered this, but as I reconsider this, doing that will allow things like having a max and min value, such as 0, 100 (0 will be static), and limit if the health can be increased or not... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
class Damage
{
public:
    Damage(int a, int b = 0, int c = 0)
        : damage(a), dotDamage(b), dotDamageLength(c)
    {

    }

    int GetDamage() const { return damage; }
private:
    int damage;
    int dotDamage;
    int dotDamageLength;
};
int& operator -=(int& n, const Damage& damage)
{
    n -= damage.GetDamage();
    return n;
}
int operator -(int n, const Damage& damage)
{
    return n - damage.GetDamage();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking to do is define an operator to convert `Damage` to an int:

```
class Damage
{
public:
    // ...
    operator int () const
    {
        return this->GetDamage();
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/AvFWNC).

Now that `Damage` has an implicit conversion to `int`, you can use it in places where such a conversion is desired. In your case, subtraction:

```
Damage d; // assume that default damage dealt is 3
int health = 4;
health -= d; // health is now 1
```