# My understanding of friend functions

Tags: c++, member, friend

Sometimes a non-member function may need access to the private members it's taking in as a agrument. 
A `friend` function is a non-member function that gives private access to the classes it's friends with.

```
Class X{
    int number;
public:
    X& operator+=(const X& rhs);//a += b is a.operator(b)
    friend int& operator+=(int& addthis, const X& rhs);//add this += b is I don't know what lol
}
X& operator+=(const X& rhs){
    this->number = this->number + rhs.number;        
}
int& operator+=(int& addthis, const X& rhs){
     addthis = addthis + rhs.number;
     return *this;
}
```

What I read is that if I wanted to do `+=` to an object, `object += int`, just overload the `+=` operator, but what if the `int` came before the object. Say `int += object`? Than I would have to write it as a `friend` function, and that's where I get a little lost. Why can't I just write `int& operator+=(int& addthis, const X& hrs);` as a member function? I assume a `friend` function can work with other classes since it's a non-member function, so it's not assigned to any specific class?

I'm sorry I just don't understand why I would use `friend` function over making it a member function. Really would appreciate any feedback, thank you.

Comment: In the `X& operator+=(const X& rhs);` definition you need to resolve `X`'s scope, ie. `X& X::operator+=(const X& rhs) { ... }`.

Comment: Does this compile? Maybe `Class` should be `class` instead?

Comment: Sorry i should of mentioned i just wrote this question now, to get a better understanding of friend functions and members and post a question, i have working code already thats not this. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Operator Overloading with Primitive Types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259534/c-operator-overloading-with-primitive-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider you implemented operator overloading as member function and performed something like `x += y` where both `x` and `y` are objects of the class which has the operator `+=` overloaded.

Compiler parses `x += y` as `x.operator+=(y)` which is fine as both operands `x` and `y` are of the same class which has the operator `+=` overloaded.

Now consider an expression like `2 += y` (this may be insane, but I am trying explain why operator overloading with friend functions may be at time beneficial over operator overloading with member functions)

Since, the expression `2 += y` will be parsed by compiler as `2.operator+=(y)`, an error is raised. Maybe `2` may get converted to an object of the class using constructor for conversion; (Single argument constructors can be used for conversion) but that is not the point here.

Using friend function to overload the operator calls the above expression `2 += y` as `operator+=(2, y)` which works fine.

Comment: Actually in my lab, the prof gave us, inside int main,something like       value += object where value was a double. Object contained amount, a private variable double for money you have.  So what you wrote made a lot of sense and doesn't sound insane to me.

Comment: ok :) In case this answer solved your question, do mark it as the solution

Comment: Your answer is wrong because 1) `2` is not converted to a class and 2) it is not "always preferable.."

Comment: Using non-member functions does allow conversion of both operands, but it isn't always preferable.  It is generally better to use non-member functions when they strictly depend on public values though.

Comment: Ok. Edited. Regarding `2` not being converted to a class it can be disabled by declaring the constructor `explicit`

Comment: @Jason, yes, but operator += should return the same type as the lhs argument, so this does not apply here.

Comment: @alain I agree `operator@=` should always return the `LHS` type (in general).  You should generally avoid exposing private data as well though.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable the `operator+=` for `int` and other integral types via a user-defined conversion in your class `X`:

```
struct X{
    int number;
    operator int() const
    {
        return number;
    }
    //...
}
```

Of course, this doesn't give you exactly the same behaviour as your `friend`-approach, as other functions could also use the conversion. Nevertheless, I guess this is what you are looking for, as otherwise you would need to define as well `operator-=`, `operator*=` and so on.

Comment: `int()` should probably be public.

Comment: @Jason: sure, and `Class` should probably be `struct` ;-) Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you can't have `operator*`, `operator+` or `operator+=` or any of `operator@` where `@` is some math operator that returns something other than an instance of your class right in the definition of your class.

In real world, it would be quite odd to add an integer to an integer and get *an apple* as a result. The same should apply to classes in C++. A member function is, well, a property of the class, a function that represents whatever can be done to the object of this class. Operators are special. They represent operations that sort of can't be made easier (what will you use to *code an addition operator* using the `+` sign instead of operator overloading?). They represent the very basic operations and thus should return an instance of the class they're members of.

Comment: Oh i get it, so the reason why i used a friend function in my example is cause theres no way i could return an int& if it was a member function, however i still needed access to the private variables (add an int to a object, and return an int) Ooooooo, wow thanks i love you lol.

Comment: I would more generally state that operations should be algebraically consistent. You can add `X + X` and get a `Y` -- in fact this is done all the time in template metaprogramming. You can also have `Y = X + Y`, but then you should also enforce `Y = Y + X`, i.e. the commutation law.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the operator `int += X` has to be a free function is that the compiler only searches for applicable member operators in the lhs type, and not in the rhs type. Since `int` is not a type that can be extended, you can't define this operator as a member function.

You were almost there, just a few errors:

```
class X;

int operator+=(int addthis, const X& rhs);

class X{
    int number;
public:
    X& operator+=(const X& rhs);//a += b is a.operator(b)
    friend int operator+=(int addthis, const X& rhs);//add this += b is I don't know what lol
};

X& X::operator+=(const X& rhs){
    this->number = this->number + rhs.number; 
    return *this;
}
int operator+=(int addthis, const X& rhs){
     addthis = addthis + rhs.number;
     return addthis;
}
```

- some forward declarations added
- `int` passed by value instead of by reference
- missing semicolon after class declaration
- `class` instead of `Class`
- `return` corrected

Note that `X += int` is a member function, while `int += X` is a free function, declared a `friend` of the class X.

Using a free function for `int += X` is the only solution that allows to use the operator as usual, like:

```
X x;
int i = 2;
i += x;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `friend` modifier is just meant to expose `private` data.  Normally, you wouldn't define a `friend` function as a non-member if it only depends on the private data of a class it can be defined as a member function for.

A better example would be `ostream::operator<<` or `istream::operator>>`.